# How to make ionic app attractive like professional apps?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an ionic app with general login & sign up functionalities. I know how to do this. But how to make the app look attractive like the apps we see in the google play store. Not just the login screen but all screens present in the app.

Is it actually possible or not?

P.S. Not a programming question but the answer to this question will be helpful to many people like me.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - can you be more specific about your issue? It sounds like you need to give it a try and come back when you're done if you need help improving the ui.

Comment: Define 'look attractive'

Comment: i want the my app to look more professional just like other apps in the playstore...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make Ionic apps look "attractive", professional, "insert another cool word here". But, I'm guessing you're more interested into *how*.

Well, since Ionic needs nothing more than CSS and HTML for the "looks", you would do it the same way as you would for a "normal website".

Bottom line, you would need to hone your skills as a web designer (specialized for the mobile UI/UX). Or, well, hire one.

Good luck!

Comment: is there any tutorial or something that may give me a hint about this?

Comment: This may be a good start: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/. Though, honestly, I'm sure a lot of people will confirm it, this is not something you'll learn from one or two tutorials...

Comment: yes yes but I wanted to start from somewhere.. thanks !

Comment: No problem, glad if I helped. In case I did help, consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: couldn't find anything related to ionic over there